# Type '"MALE"' is not assignable to type 'UserGender'

Tags: node.js, typescript, enums, interface

this is my code

```
enum UserGender {
  MALE = "MALE",
  FEMALE = "FEMALE",
  OTHER = "OTHER",
}

enum UserRegistrationStatus {
  ACTIVE = "ACTIVE",
  UNACTIVE = "UNACTIVE",
}

interface User {
  lastName: string;
  firstName: string;
  nickName: string;
  img: string;
  email: string;
  gender: UserGender;
  age: string;
  salt: string;
  password: string;
  registrationStatus: UserRegistrationStatus;
}


const user: User | null = {
    lastName: "asda",
    firstName: "asdasd",
    nickName: "asdasdasda5de9ff131b",
    img: "string",
    email: "darkasdacasvsaasalte@gmail.com",
    gender: "MALE",
    age: "dasdas",
    salt: "$2a$10$ARAjZHbqPY7fkvl8v.qfgO",
    password: "$2a$10$ARAjZHbqPY7fkvl8v.qfgO2gQmatjHyivuoFtRxAAIHvJUidon6I2",
    registrationStatus: "ACTIVE",
  };
```

I get this error

***Type '"MALE"' is not assignable to type 'UserGender'.***,

***Type '"ACTIVE"' is not assignable to type 'UserRegistrationStatus'.***

What am I doing wrong. How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just wants you to use the enum, not a string literal. For example:

```
gender: UserGender.MALE,
// ...
registrationStatus: UserRegistrationStatus.ACTIVE,
```